# Use Spine in Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, spine

In cocos2dx, I use the class `skeletonAnimation` to create the skeleton animation which uses the resources exported by spine. We know the class `skeletonAnimation` is the subclass of node not is sprite.
 How to do to make the skeleton animation flip the node as it like to use the method `setFlippedX()` in sprite node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method Which is inherited from class Node: **setScaleX(-1)**, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had created methods to flip the skeleton animation.

```
void setFlipX(bool flipX) {
    if(flippedX != flipX) {
        flippedX = flipX;
        flippedX ? setScaleX(-getScaleX()) : setScaleX(getScaleX());
    }
}

void setFlipY(bool flipY) {
    if(flippedY != flipY) {
        flippedY = flipY;
        flippedY ? setScaleY(-getScaleX()) : setScaleY(getScaleX());
    }
}
```

and call the it as:

```
spinefile->setFlipX(true);

spinefile->setFlipY(true);
```